# Binding data to a Data Repeater - VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datarepeater

I'm looking for a line or two of code that will bind a DataSet.Datatable column to a textbox on a Datarepeater?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of you need to bind dataset to Repeater.
DataRepeater.DataSource = Dataset.Table("name")
DataRepeater.DataBind()

and then find your Textbox Text="" property and set there <%# Bind("columnname") %>

Comment: There does not seem to be a DataRepeater.DataBind() method.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty good How-to video on MSDN that covers the DataRepeater.  I'd suggest taking a look there.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/cc411420.aspx